# What's stopping weblogic form authentication from forwarding to the protected page?

Tags: jsf, authentication, jakarta-ee, weblogic

We are building a fairly simple secured web application (let's call it new-app) using JSF on WebLogic 10.3 (pre-Servlet3.0). We are using form authentication to protect a set of secure pages, marked out by their being located in a subcontext, foo.

So we have an application context root that is: www.example.com/new-app, and some secured pages like www.example.com/new-app/foo/bar.jsf.

When we request bar.jsf, the container responds as expected, our login form is shown and the login happens correctly. However, rather than forwarding to the protected resource (bar.jsf) the redirect we get is the root context.

Anyone encountered this, and knows what is going on?

Comment: The 'wrong' page is returned? Please read [ask] on how to ask questions.

Comment: Yes, the page returned would be  something like www.example.com/new-app/index.jsf, depending on what is configured in the web.xml welcome-file-list. My point is that weblogic shouldn't be resorting to the welcome-file-list, rather it should be returning the originally requested protected resource.